# Why is it that when I submit my form, only the general styles are being captured in $_POST and not the @media styles?

Tags: php, html, forms, post

The problem I encounter is during the update of styles (both general and @media). The result of submitting my form, print_r($_POST), only displays the general styles. It also seems that only one transmitted value is taken into account.

As part of a CMS where style pages are encoded in a database to be able to modify them and (re)generate the CSS file, I have a PHP page that displays the data based on the CSS page ID received via $_GET page.php?id=1. So far, everything is fine; both general styles and specific @media styles are displayed perfectly.

I have my respective form fields for the general styles written as follows:

```html
    <input type="text" name="<?= $item['property_name'] . '_' . $item['styles_id']; ?>" class="form-control form-control-sm" value="<?= htmlspecialchars_decode($item['property_value']); ?>">
```

And for the @media styles like this:

```html
    <input type="text" name="<?= $max_600px_style['property_name'] . '_' . $max_600px_style['styles_id']; ?>" class="form-control form-control-sm" value="<?= htmlspecialchars_decode($max_600px_style['property_sm_value']); ?>">
```

Iterated by foreach.

HTML of the form:

```html
<form method="post" action="processing.php">
    <!-- Fields for general styles -->
    <div class="row pb-1">
        <div class="col-xl-3">btn-caption</div>
        <div class="col-xl-3">color</div>
        <div class="col-xl-3"><input type="text" name="color_23" class="form-control form-control-sm" value="#808080"></div>
        <div class="col-xl-1"><input type="text" name="" class="form-control form-control-sm" value="Yes"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- Fields for @media styles -->
    <div class="row pb-1">
        <div class="col-xl-3">btn-caption</div>
        <div class="col-xl-3">font-size</div>
        <div class="col-xl-3"><input type="text" name="font-size_max600_25" class="form-control form-control-sm" value="9px !important"></div>
        <div class="col-xl-3"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

PHP for processing form data (processing.php):

```php
// Display data received via $_POST
print_r($_POST);
```

Result of $_POST after form submission:

```php
Array
(
    [color_23] => #80808
    [background-color_24] => #f5f5f5
    [font-size_25] => 10px !important
    [font-family_26] => 'Acme-Regular', sans-serif
    [text-transform_27] => uppercase
    [background-color_28] => #f5f5f5
    [color_29] => #8A2BE2
    [right_9] => 15%
    [bottom_10] => 0.7rem
    [left_11] => 5%
    [padding-top_12] => 1.25rem
    [padding-bottom_13] => 1.25rem
    [text-align_14] => left
    [font-size_20] => 1rem
    [font-family_21] => 'Dosis-Bold', sans-serif
    [color_22] => #fff
    [font-size_17] => 1.75rem
    [font-family_18] => 'Josefin-Bold', sans-serif
    [color_19] => #242424
    [maj] => 
)
```

Here's roughly what's happening, or I should say what's not happening. But no matter how hard I look, I can't seem to figure out where the issue lies.

Comment: We have no idea what you actually have in those variables, so we can't know what HTML this actually produces. Show the rendered output, please.

Comment: Using `htmlspecialchars_decode` on values you are putting _into_ an HTML context, looks highly suspicious.

Comment: Why suspicious ? and why not at the end ?

Comment: _"Why suspicious ?"_ - because it is the exact opposite, of what normally _should_ be done in a situation like this. Again, we don't know your _data_, so we don't know what this will eventually result in - but chance are, that this is most likely the _completely_ wrong thing to do at that point.

Comment: ```html
<div class="col-xl-3"><input type="text" name="color_23" class="form-control form-control-sm" value="#80808"></div>
\``` that's the output HTML

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mre] of the issue including all relevant code and sample data. Two out-of-context lines of code, and one unattributed line of data are not forming a coherent picture of the situation. See also [ask]. Thanks.

Comment: I trying to editing but I can't place my code correctly in compliance with the "standards" so too bad

Comment: Why not? What is the editor complaining about when you try? Everyone else seems to manage it. Have a look at [How do I format my posts?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) in case you need some assistance.

Comment: I'm perhaps less gifted than the others with markdown ;-), I'll see about that later, thanks

Comment: I finally managed to adapt my post. I hope it's okay and clearer now.

Comment: Thanks. But... `Result of $_POST after form submission`...the POSTed data you've shown doesn't match the HTML form you've shown, at all. That form only has 2 fields, so it simply can't have posted all that. Make sure you show us a [mre] of the issue, with coherent code and data samples, please.